# How to import node module or JavaScript file without webpack dependency when using create-react-app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm trying to include a separate JavaScript file (server.js) from my index.js file using create-react-app. This server.js file uses the `npm zeromq` node module which doesn't seem to play well with webpack. Because of this, I'm either trying to exclude the `zeromq` node module or server.js.

I'm made attempts to edit webpack.config.js with no luck. Some of what I I've tried:

```
{
  ...
  test: /\.(js|mjs|jsx)$/,
  exclude: /server\.js$/,
  ...
}
```

Unfortunately all the examples I have found look nothing like the config file I currently have. My generated config from project/node_modules/webpack/config looks something like this...

```
...
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';
...
```

I import the server.js file from index.js in a standard way.

```
import './server.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

So it's possible that your issue is that you just need to have

```
import server from './server.js';
```

Or whatever specific module it is you need. That being said, if you are having issues with something being incompatible with webpack it might be worth trying a require statement instead. So something like:

```
const server = require('./server.js');
```

Also have you ejected your react app? It's often easier to modify parts of your build scripts if you've ejected an app created with create-react-app.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! I'll do some research into rejecting and see if that works and get back to the post.